# NUnit - how to test operation twice using custom setting each time

Tags: nunit, playwright

I would like to know how to test propertly via NUnit same operation.
Each call should set parameter to static property. I am looking for similiar `TestCase` implementation.

Usage:

```
[DesktopTest, MobileTest]
public async Task ShouldA()
{
}
```

NUnit is using Playwright framework. Intention is to use different viewport size without passing parameter like

```
[TestCase("desktop")]
[TestCase("mobile")]
public async Task ShouldA(string device)
{
}
```

My current implementation of `DesktopTest`

```
public class DesktopTestAttribute : TestCaseAttribute
{
   public DesktopTestAttribute() : base()
   {
      TestManager.SetDevice("desktop"); // static class
   }
}
```

However constructor is followed by `MobileTest` constructor which override device.

What is proper way to not set mobile device if I run desktop target?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use TestFixture inheritance:

```
public class TestManager
{
    public static void SetDevice(string device) => Device = device;

    public static string Device { get; private set; }
}

public abstract class BaseFixture
{
    protected BaseFixture(string device)
    {
        TestManager.SetDevice(device);

        this.device = device;
    }

    [Test]
    public void ShouldA() => Assert.That(TestManager.Device, Is.EqualTo(device));

    private string device;
}

[TestFixture]
public class DesktopTest: BaseFixture
{
    public DesktopTest(): base("desktop") { }
}

[TestFixture]
public class MobileTest: BaseFixture
{
    public MobileTest(): base("mobile") { }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I figured out eventually like you saying via TestFixture.. but you have cooler way.